# Cannot attach to phoenix server

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to elixir and phoenix, please help:

Start phx server:

```
$ iex --sname myapp --cookie mycookie -S mix phx.server
```

Attach to it:

```
$ iex --sname debug --cookie mycookie --remsh myapp@localhost

Could not start IEx CLI due to reason: :noconnection
```

Answer (score 0):

`--sname` might be broken, as I couldn't get it to work either. However, using `--name` works:

```elixir
$ iex --name myapp --cookie mycookie
Erlang/OTP 26 [erts-14.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Interactive Elixir (1.15.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(myapp@Arya.local)1>
```

```elixir
$ iex --name debug --cookie mycookie --remsh myapp
Erlang/OTP 26 [erts-14.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Interactive Elixir (1.15.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(myapp@Arya.local)1> node()
:"myapp@Arya.local"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Your answer works, But Why I try to using `--remsh myapp@127.0.0.1` with 127.0.0.1 to attach will failed?

Comment: The argument to `--remsh` is a single string representing the node name that must match the result of `node()`.